# storage account is not available when creating function app in azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Please see the image. When I am trying to create new function app, I am unable to select storage because that option is not available.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xN8R.png

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the page.

Comment: @FrankGong I have tried refreshing many occasions

Comment: Have you tried to change the settings in Basics, such as Region

Comment: @FrankGong Yes, I have change regions of storage accounts and the function app

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug, you can seek help from Microsoft official technical support here:

[image]

Comment: yes that is the final solution for me. Thank you